# Get JWT authenticated user in Laravel 5.4 model

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-5.4

I am pretty much new to Laravel so sorry if it is basic or duplicate question.
I need to somehow get the JWT authenticated user id in my model in Laravel 5.4.
Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify what you are using, fella!!

If you're using tymon's jwt, you can identify the owner of a token by:

```
JWTAuth::setToken("token_string");
JWTAuth::authenticate(); //this returns the user
```

So, in order to retrieve the user's ID:

```
JWTAuth::setToken("token_string");
$user_id = JWTAuth::authenticate()->id;
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Yep, I'm using tymon's JWT and this is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much buddy!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Laravel Passport for JWT you can simply get user details by `Auth::guard('api')->user()`

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response. Since I am not using Passport, is there any other way to get the user?

Comment: It depends on the package you are using ... It should be in the documentation. There's no specific way to get the user details ...
Like `tymondesigns/jwt-auth` is a very popular package for JWT auth ... if you are using this package, you can retrieve user details by  `JWTAuth::parseToken()->toUser()` ... So read the documentation of the psckage ...

Comment: Yep, I'm using tymons JWT. Thanks mate!